# RxPY concurrency

Tags: python, concurrency, reactivex, rx-py

I'm trying to understand what operations are serialized and what are not with RxPY. So I printed out thread names and current delay in seconds during `map` and `subscribe` calls in the example below.

I was expecting the delay in seconds for `map` operation should be in [1,2,3,4,5] seconds. However, I've got [1,3,5,7,9] seconds for `map`. The additional delay of 2s for `subscribe` is expected due to `time.sleep(2)` during `map`. Why is that? It looks like `map` on the 2nd element won't start until `subscribe` call finished for the 1st element, despite 1st element and 2nd element have their respective threads for both `map` and `subscribe`.

```py
import reactivex as rx
import concurrent
import time
from reactivex import operators as ops
from threading import current_thread
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(5) as executor:
    start = time.time()
    rx.range(1, 6).pipe(
        ops.flat_map(lambda s: rx.from_future(executor.submit(lambda x: time.sleep(x) or x, s))),
        ops.map(lambda x: print('map', current_thread().name, time.time()-start,x) or time.sleep(2) or x)
    ).subscribe(lambda x: print('sub', current_thread().name,time.time()-start,x))
```

Gives output:

```
map ThreadPoolExecutor-21_0 1.0019810199737549 1
sub ThreadPoolExecutor-21_0 3.0042216777801514 1
map ThreadPoolExecutor-21_1 3.004584789276123 2
sub ThreadPoolExecutor-21_1 5.006811141967773 2
map ThreadPoolExecutor-21_2 5.007160663604736 3
sub ThreadPoolExecutor-21_2 7.008445978164673 3
map ThreadPoolExecutor-21_4 7.008780241012573 5
sub ThreadPoolExecutor-21_4 9.01101279258728 5
map ThreadPoolExecutor-21_3 9.01136064529419 4
sub ThreadPoolExecutor-21_3 11.013587951660156 4
```

How can I process these 5 elements using 5 threads w/o additional wait while keeping thread affinity (each element is only processed by the same thread across all operators in the pipe)? Similar to behavior below with `ParallelStream`/`pseq` provided by `pyfunctional` package but using ideally a threadpool instead of processes.

```
import time
from functional import pseq
from multiprocessing import current_process
start = time.time()
pseq(range(1, 6)).map(lambda x: time.sleep(x) or x)\
    .map(lambda x:print('map', current_process().name, time.time()-start, x) or time.sleep(2) or x)\
    .map(lambda x:print('sub', current_process().name, time.time()-start, x) or x)
```

with output

```
map ForkPoolWorker-80 1.0282073020935059 1
map ForkPoolWorker-81 2.031876802444458 2
sub ForkPoolWorker-80 3.0305001735687256 1
map ForkPoolWorker-82 3.035196304321289 3
sub ForkPoolWorker-81 4.034159898757935 2
map ForkPoolWorker-83 4.038431644439697 4
sub ForkPoolWorker-82 5.03748893737793 3
map ForkPoolWorker-84 5.038834571838379 5
sub ForkPoolWorker-83 6.040730953216553 4
sub ForkPoolWorker-84 7.0410990715026855 5
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```